# ShinyApp disconnects after two clicks

Tags: r, shinyapps

I would like to deploy a predictive model via a ShinyApp. My app works locally but when I publish it online, it disconnects after two clicks. Any Idea why that is the case? You can check out the link below to check the website and use the code below to reproduce the error. Any comment would be appreciated. I've spent so much time already trying to figure it out but I have no more ideas.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidymodels)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(plotly)
library(ranger)
library(caret)


model_rate <- readRDS("model_forest_rate.rds")
model_rate_activism <- readRDS("model_forest_rate_activism.rds")

# function to predict the probability 
predict_probability <- function(model, dat){
    stats::predict(model, dat, type = "prob") %>%
        tidyr::gather() %>%
        dplyr::mutate(value = as.numeric(value)) 
}

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
# Define UI for app that draws a histogram ----
ui <- fluidPage(

    # App title ----
    titlePanel("Auswertung der Umfrageergebnisse zur Abstimmung des CO2-Gesetz vom 13.06.21"),

    # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
    sidebarLayout(
    
        # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
        sidebarPanel(

            selectInput("pol_party", label = "Welche Partei entspricht in den Zielen und Forderungen am ehesten Ihren eigenen 
                        Ansichten und Wünschen?",
                        choices = c("SVP (Schweizerische Volkspartei)", 
                                    "SP (Sozialdemokratische Partei)", 
                                    "FDP.Die Liberalen (Freisinnig Demokratische Partei)", 
                                    "CVP (Christlichdemokratische Volkspartei)",
                                    "GPS (Grüne Partei Schweiz)",
                                    "GLP (Grünliberale Partei)",
                                    "BDP (Bürgerlich Demokratische Partei)",
                                    "EVP (Evangelische Volkspartei der Schweiz)",
                                    "Lega dei Ticinesi",
                                    "PdA (Partei der Arbeit Schweiz)",
                                    "MCG (Mouvement Citoyens Genevois)",
                                    "CSP (Christlichsoziale Partei Schweiz)",
                                    "EDU (Eidgenössisch-Demokratische Union)",
                                    "Sol. (SolidaritéS)",
                                    "Andere:",
                                    "Keine",
                                    "Weiss nicht / keine Antwort")
            ),
        
        ),
    
        # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
        mainPanel(
        
            # Output: Histogram ----
            plotOutput(outputId = "Plot1", height = "200px")
            # ,plotOutput(outputId = "Plot2", height = "200px")
        
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {



    output$Plot1 <- renderPlot({
  
    
        dat <- tibble(
           "civi_stat" = 1,
            "fin_cond" = 1,
            "pol_party" = if(input$pol_party == "SVP (Schweizerische Volkspartei)") {1}
            else if (input$pol_party == "SP (Sozialdemokratische Partei)") {2}
            else if (input$pol_party == "FDP.Die Liberalen (Freisinnig Demokratische Partei)") {3}
            else if (input$pol_party == "CVP (Christlichdemokratische Volkspartei)") {4}
            else if (input$pol_party == "GPS (Grüne Partei Schweiz)") {5}
            else if (input$pol_party == "GLP (Grünliberale Partei)") {6}
            else if (input$pol_party == "BDP (Bürgerlich Demokratische Partei)") {7}
            else if (input$pol_party == "EVP (Evangelische Volkspartei der Schweiz)") {8}
            else if (input$pol_party == "Lega dei Ticinesi") {9}
            else if (input$pol_party == "PdA (Partei der Arbeit Schweiz)") {10}
            else if (input$pol_party == "MCG (Mouvement Citoyens Genevois)") {11}
            else if (input$pol_party == "CSP (Christlichsoziale Partei Schweiz)") {12}
            else if (input$pol_party == "EDU (Eidgenössisch-Demokratische Union)") {13}
            else if (input$pol_party == "Sol. (SolidaritéS)") {14}
            else if (input$pol_party == "Andere:") {15}
            else if (input$pol_party == "Keine") {16}
            else if (input$pol_party == "Weiss nicht / keine Antwort") {17},
            "renew_heating" = 1,
            "left_right" = 1,
            "prior_benefit" = 1,
            "ren_driver" = 1,
            "home_owner" = 1,
            "educ" = 1,
            "empl_sect" = 1,
            "empl_stat" = 2,
            "gender" = 1,
            "region" = 1,
            "know_targ" = 1,
            "know_build" = 1,
            "know_trans" = 1,
            "know_food" = 1,
            "know_avia" = 1,
            "know_wast" = 1,
            "efficiency" = 3,
            "effectiveness" = 3,
            "competitiveness" = 3,
            "justice" = 3,
            "transformation" = 3
       
        )
    
            predict_probability(model_rate, dat) %>%
             dplyr::mutate(
              value = ifelse(key == ".pred_2", value*(-1), value),
              value = ifelse(key == ".pred_1", value*(-1), value),
              value = ifelse(key == ".pred_3", value/2, value),
              dv = ""
            ) %>%
            dplyr::bind_rows(.[.$key == ".pred_3",] %>% dplyr::mutate(value = value *(-1))) %>%
            dplyr::mutate(key = factor(key, levels = c(".pred_3", ".pred_2", ".pred_1", ".pred_4", ".pred_5"))) %>%
            ggplot2::ggplot(.) +
            ggplot2::geom_bar(aes(x = dv, y = value, fill = key), stat = "identity", position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
            ggplot2::theme_minimal() +
            ggplot2::coord_flip() +
            ggplot2::ylim(-1,1) +
            ggplot2::labs(
            title = "Public Support",
            x = "",
            y = "Probability"
        ) +
            ggplot2::scale_fill_manual(name = "", labels =c("Viel Aufwand zur Unterstützung", "Etwas Aufwand zur Unterstützung", "Viel Aufwand zur Verhinderung", "Etwas Aufwand zur Verhinderung", "Weder noch"), limits = rev, values = c("darkgreen", "lightgreen", "red4", "red3",  "grey")) +
        ggplot2::theme(plot.title = element_text(margin = ggplot2::margin(30,30,30,30)), legend.position = "bottom") +
        guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=2,byrow=TRUE))
   
    })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[link](https://simon-andres-montfort.shinyapps.io/PredictingVote/) to the app

[two models](https://www.swisstransfer.com/d/118259b9-570d-4f0c-8b6c-d492975a87f4) for download

Logs:

```
2022-06-27T10:46:35.294545+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: ✔ parsnip      0.2.1     ✔ workflowsets 0.2.1
2022-06-27T10:46:35.294454+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: ✔ infer        1.0.2     ✔ tune         0.2.0
2022-06-27T10:46:35.294633+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: ── Conflicts ───────────────────────────────────────── tidymodels_conflicts() ──
2022-06-27T10:46:35.294310+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: ✔ dials        1.0.0     ✔ rsample      0.1.1
2022-06-27T10:46:35.294849+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: ✖ recipes::step()  masks stats::step()
2022-06-27T10:46:35.294502+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: ✔ modeldata    0.1.1     ✔ workflows    0.2.6
2022-06-27T10:46:35.294590+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: ✔ purrr        0.3.4     ✔ yardstick    1.0.0
2022-06-27T10:46:35.295012+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: ✔ readr   2.1.2     ✔ forcats 0.5.1
2022-06-27T10:46:35.294806+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: ✖ infer::observe() masks shiny::observe()
2022-06-27T10:46:35.294894+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: • Dig deeper into tidy modeling with R at https://www.tmwr.org
2022-06-27T10:46:35.294719+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: ✖ dplyr::filter()  masks stats::filter()
2022-06-27T10:46:35.294762+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: ✖ dplyr::lag()     masks stats::lag()
2022-06-27T10:46:35.295062+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: ✔ stringr 1.4.0     
2022-06-27T10:46:35.294676+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: ✖ purrr::discard() masks scales::discard()
2022-06-27T10:46:35.294962+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: ── Attaching packages ─────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.3.1 ──
2022-06-27T10:46:36.296606+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: ── Conflicts ────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
2022-06-27T10:46:36.296676+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: ✖ readr::col_factor() masks scales::col_factor()
2022-06-27T10:46:36.296744+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: ✖ purrr::discard()    masks scales::discard()
2022-06-27T10:46:36.296792+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: ✖ dplyr::filter()     masks stats::filter()
2022-06-27T10:46:36.296851+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: ✖ stringr::fixed()    masks recipes::fixed()
2022-06-27T10:46:36.296898+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: ✖ dplyr::lag()        masks stats::lag()
2022-06-27T10:46:36.296988+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: 
2022-06-27T10:46:36.296944+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: ✖ readr::spec()       masks yardstick::spec()
2022-06-27T10:46:36.297127+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: The following object is masked from ‘package:ggplot2’:
2022-06-27T10:46:36.297032+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: Attaching package: ‘plotly’
2022-06-27T10:46:36.297077+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: 
2022-06-27T10:46:36.297213+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]:     last_plot
2022-06-27T10:46:36.297170+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: 
2022-06-27T10:46:36.297257+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: 
2022-06-27T10:46:36.297304+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:
2022-06-27T10:46:36.297345+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: 
2022-06-27T10:46:36.297476+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]:     filter
2022-06-27T10:46:36.297529+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: 
2022-06-27T10:46:36.297583+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:
2022-06-27T10:46:36.297634+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: 
2022-06-27T10:46:36.297679+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]:     layout
2022-06-27T10:46:36.297724+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: 
2022-06-27T10:46:36.297784+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: Loading required package: lattice
2022-06-27T10:46:36.297830+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: 
2022-06-27T10:46:36.297875+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: Attaching package: ‘caret’
2022-06-27T10:46:36.297918+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: 
2022-06-27T10:46:36.297966+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:yardstick’:
2022-06-27T10:46:36.298010+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: 
2022-06-27T10:46:36.298054+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]:     precision, recall, sensitivity, specificity
2022-06-27T10:46:36.298095+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: 
2022-06-27T10:46:36.298162+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: The following object is masked from ‘package:purrr’:
2022-06-27T10:46:36.298207+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: 
2022-06-27T10:46:36.298254+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]:     lift
2022-06-27T10:46:36.298300+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: 
2022-06-27T10:46:43.294162+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: 
2022-06-27T10:46:43.294219+00:00 shinyapps[5076563]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:42379
```

Comment: Can you include the error messages from the server logs? See here: https://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/Troubleshooting.html#disconnected-from-server-messages (I most often get that message when I forgot to provide a library the app depends on; of course there's more ways to crash the session)

Comment: edited the post with logs. thank you.

Comment: can you not reproduce the error?

Comment: While it wouldn't hurt to have a closer look on why your app demands the Anaconda environment anyway, the bottom 4 lines of the log suggest to examine the special characters in your variable(?) names and make sure that characters (e.g Umlaute) are UTF-8 encoded: https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-in-deploying-a-shinyapp-to-shinyapps-io/110934/3

Comment: I've updated the code so that these messages do not appear in the logs anymore (deleted the unused DALEX package and change the relabelling of collumns). The problem with the disconnected server persists after publishing the adapted code and ShinyApp.